# Hiera loop through array with lookup

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am trying to get certain value from merged array that should be looked up in hiera.

```
%{lookup('profile::aclass::avalue.(.name == "test")')}
```

The example is showing lookup for value of profile class where avalue is type of `Array[Hash[String, Any]]`. The expression should lookup for every value where the name of `Hash` type has value of string `"test"`.
I would like to select only this element of array.

The problem is the value can be everywhere in Array can I cannot use expression `profile::aclass::avalue.0`

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what the example interpolation is supposed to mean, and I have only a vague idea of what the target Hiera data are supposed to look like.  For us -- or at least me -- to help you, I think we need a [mre].

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hi, I have updated the question. I hope it's more clear now what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you saying that the `(.name == "test")` is supposed to be some kind of query predicate?  That is, "I want the object(s) that have a `name` key with value `'test'`"?  Hiera does not support anything much like that.  You're being very coy about the actual data and data structure involved, but my first impression is that it is probably structured suboptimally, or else that what you're trying to do with that `%lookup` would be better done in DSL code, if at all.

Comment: Hi back John, yes I wasn't sure whether is something like that possible but it would be great to have something like this. It would open more possibilities how to write cleaner and better code. There should be this somewhere in preprocessor.

Comment: You are of course welcome to submit a feature request.  Do note, however, that Puppet has no preprocessor. Interpolation functions such as `%lookup` are processed dynamically, when the data in which they appear are retrieved.  Also note that I still think there is probably a better way to achieve the end result you are after, but you have not given enough information for anyone to make a recommendation about that.